# Load All Task Items in to Page?

Tags: development, jquery, tasks, task-list

I have Task list in home page containing multiple task items,

Is it possible to approve multiple items at once, instead of one at a time (being redirected to the start page after each approval..) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
string Url = SPContext.Current.Site.Url.ToString();

            using (SPSite site1 = new SPSite(Url))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site1.OpenWeb())
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    SPUser me = web.CurrentUser;
                    SPList list = web.Lists["Tasks"];
                    SPQuery qurey = new SPQuery();
                    qurey.Query = "<Where><And><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='Integer'><UserID /></Value></Eq><Membership Type='CurrentUserGroups'><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo'/></Membership></Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>Not Started</Value></Eq></And></Where>";
                    qurey.ViewFields = "<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False'/></OrderBy></Query></View>";
                    qurey.RowLimit = 2;                    
                    SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(qurey);
                    //TaskGrid.DataSource = items.GetDataTable();
                    //TaskGrid.DataBind();
                    if (items.Count != 0)
                    {
                        foreach (SPListItem taskitem in items)
                        {

                            Label1.Text = "Next Task Item ID" + taskitem["ID"];
                            var itemd = taskitem["ID"];
                            if (taskitem["ID"] != null)
                            {
                                Response.Redirect("http://site.com/Lists/Tasks/DispForm.aspx?" + "ID=" + itemd + "&ContentTypeId=0x010800C403738557E42A48815786B56111DD3C");
                            }


                        }
                    }
                    else {

                        Response.Redirect("http://site.com");
                    }
```

Event Fire After Approve the Task and Get The Next Task Related to Current User using SPQurey.